# Unexpected Airflow behaviour in dynamic task generation

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

For reasons acceptable to me, I am trying to dynamically generate `ExternalTaskSensor` tasks with different `execution_date_fn` in each iteration. Callable provided to `execution_date_fn` kwarg requires to have `dt` as input and provide `execution_date` as output, which I am writing down as a lambda function, e.g. `lambda dt: get_execution_date(i)`.

I noticed that `execution_date_fn` provided as a lambda function in a loop results in unexpected behaviour - all generated tasks have the same `execution_date`

I noticed that this behaviour is not intrinsic to `ExternalTaskSensor` but originates somewhere else. This behaviour can be seen in this example:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    'test_lambda',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021,1,1),
    catchup=False
)

for task_id in ['task1', 'task2']:
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='printer_'+task_id,
        python_callable=lambda: print(task_id),
        dag=dag
    )
```

This results in both tasks `printer_task1` and `printer_task2` printing `'task2'` in logs.

I have managed to correct the behaviour by moving sensor instantiation into a function:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

def create_task(task_id):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='printer_'+task_id,
        python_callable=lambda: print(task_id),
        dag=dag
    )
    return task

dag = DAG(
    'test_lambda',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021,1,1),
    catchup=False
)

for task_id in ['task1', 'task2']:
    task = create_task(task_id)
```

In this case task `printer_task1` prints `'task1'` and `printer_task2` prints `'task2'` in the logs.

I would be interested to know why am I observing such behaviour?

DISCLAIMER: I am aware that normal way to provide arguments to a `PythonOperator` is via `op_args` kwarg. Lambda functions were used solely to provide an example as `op_args` option is not available in `ExternalTaskSensor` when using `execution_date_fn`.

EDIT: This is a `lambda` issue and not Airflow-specific. Official Python documentation has a topic on the issue: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little to do with Airflow, it is a `lambda` issue:

```py
>>> ls = [lambda: i for i in [1,2]]
>>> ls[0]()
2
>>> ls[1]()
2
```

To know why it does that, I recommend reading
[that Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture) that will probably explains why better than I could

Comment: Thanks for the link. Reading around I found that there's a section on the topic in the official Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result. I will close my question