# Automatically generating ExternalTaskSensor where execution date depends only on DAG id

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

Help me crack this one. I am looking for an elegant solution for dynamically generating `ExternalTaskSensor` tasks in Airflow with unique `execution_date_fn` functions while avoiding problems arising from function scopes.

I am trying to create a DAG that depends on several other DAGs by that they shouldn't run simultaneously. I am using `ExternalTaskSensor` operators, best illustrated visually:

[image: sensor dag]

Sensor tasks, e.g. `sense_dag_1`, rely on `DagRun` object to find the latest `execution_date` of e.g. `dag_1`. This method, called `get_execution_date` in my code, is created and passed to the `ExternalTaskOperator` via `execution_date_fn` kwarg. This works well when "manually" creating tasks as shown in example:

```py
sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='sense_dag_1',
        external_dag_id='dag_1',
        execution_date_fn=lambda dt: get_execution_date('dag_1'),
        dag=dag
    )
```

Note that a little workaround is used, providing `get_execution_date` to `ExternalTaskSensor` as a lambda function with input `dt`. This solution, however, faces a problem when automatically generating multiple `ExternalTaskSensor` tasks for a list of DAG names, as seen in naive example:

```py
for dag_id in ['dag_1', 'dag_2']:
    sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='sense_'+dag_id,
        external_dag_id=dag_id,
        execution_date_fn=lambda dt: get_execution_date(dag_id),
        dag=dag
    )
```

When creating tasks this way, all tasks are set with the same `execution_date`, coinciding with `execution_date` of the last `dag_id` in the list. I am aware that this problem is to do with functions and scope, as described in [Python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

We end up with two limiting factors:

- `execution_date_fn` only accepts `dt` and `**context` as arguments
- Lambda functions (and functions in general) require arguments defined in function scope in order to correctly assign variable values.

**QUESTION:** How do I dynamically generate `ExternalTaskSensor` tasks where `execution_date` only depends on `dag_id`?

I have one solution in mind: adding tasks upstream of sensors that get the `execution_date` and push it to `context`. However, in this case order of task execution becomes important, making the end DAG look something like this:
[image: employ context]
This is not aesthetically pleasing and I am looking for something better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered a working solution: move sensor instantiation to a separate function. This way the variable scope is separated for loop and task creation. Code example:

```py
def create_sensor(dag_id):
    task = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='sense_'+dag_id,
        external_dag_id=dag_id,
        execution_date_fn=lambda dt: get_execution_date(dag_id),
        dag=dag
    )
    return task

for dag_id in ['dag_1', 'dag_2']:
    sensor = create_sensor(dag_id)
```

More on the topic here: [Unexpected Airflow behaviour in dynamic task generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664442/unexpected-airflow-behaviour-in-dynamic-task-generation)